# Trying to retrieve a document from Firestore database using

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to React Native, I'd like to retrieve a document from my firestore database in order to display the full name field on the screen, but I've been running into trouble accessing the document. I've tried the "Get a document" tips here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#web-version-9_1 to no avail. Please let me know how I can get this working. I know the issue is with my async function, I keep getting "undefined is not an object, evaluating _n7.indexOf"

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { signOut } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "../firebase/firebase";
import Button from "react-native-button";
import { db } from "../firebase/firebase";
import { doc, getDoc, collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { useRoute } from "@react-navigation/native";

export function UserHome({ navigation }) {
  const route = useRoute();
  const userID = route.params?.userID;
  const docRef = doc(db, "userInfo", userID);
  alert(userID);
  async () => {
    console.log("it worked");
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
  };

  const handleSignOut = () => {
    signOut(auth)
      .then(() => {
        navigation.replace("Home");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // An error happened.
      });
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>You're officially in!!</Text>
      <Button
        containerStyle={{
          padding: 10,
          height: 45,
          overflow: "hidden",
          borderRadius: 20,
          backgroundColor: "#8252ff",
        }}
        disabledContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: "grey" }}
        style={{
          fontSize: 18,
          color: "white",
          textAlign: "center",
        }}
        onPress={handleSignOut}
      >
        Sign Out
      </Button>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Where are you trying to display this information? FullName is not in the JSX from your snippet. Have you tried a lifecycle hook, like `componentDidMount` to fetch the data on render?

Comment: The objective is to get the full name and display it on the screen, but so far I just wanted to see if I can retrieve the entire document.

Comment: I haven’t tried a lifecycle hook yet though @Tim